# How to Write RegEx for Google Analytics Goal Tracking ThankYou Page with Unique ID

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

`www.domain.com/home/processform/thankyou?order_id=9653&order_value=mobilebrand` as the the final URL for thank you page with unique ID.

`^/thankyou$` as RegEx - will this work to count the goal?

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: i want to convert the order id to regex since its dynamic, i have to come up with a destination thankyou page to be track. like home/processform/thankyou?order_id=\d{2,5}&order_value=mobilebrand

Comment: No your regex will not work, but you should try for yourself first and perhaps try to figure out why. How did you come up with that in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
regular expression  /thankyou
```

as the destination goal.

Answer (score 0):

If your page values in Google Analytics are formatted the default way, you'll want to use the following regex:

```
^/thankyou.*
```

If you use a '$' at the end, it won't detect any of your URLs that have query parameters, like your examples do.

Answer (score 0):

one can use the below which will only match  "/thankyou" or "/thankyou/" in any given URL

regex `\/thankyou\/?`